# How do I check if the string input from the user represents a float value?

Tags: c#

I'm working on this project where you feed and exercise your pet to keep them alive. When it comes to feeding, the game will ask you how many treats would you like to feed your pet. And to get a passing grade I need the code to detect if the input from the user is a float. So I need it to say "Please enter a number" when a string is entered instead of a float. Any ideas?

```
    // Function for feeding pet
static void FeedPet(ref float PetWeight, List<string> FeedList, List<string> ExoList, ref string PetName)
{
    bool repeat = true;
    while (repeat)
    {
        Math.Round(PetWeight, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("|=-=-=-=-=| FEED |=-=-=-=-=|");
        Console.Write($"Please enter the amount of treats you would like to feed {PetName}: ");
        float FoodAmount = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        float GainedWeight = (float)(FoodAmount * 0.02f);

        if ( FoodAmount == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"No treats for {PetName} today");
            Console.WriteLine($"{PetName} currently weighs {PetWeight}");
            repeat = false;
        }
        if ((FoodAmount >= 1) && (FoodAmount <= 5)) 
        {
            // Formula for new pet weight
            PetWeight = FoodAmount * 0.2f + PetWeight;
            // Telling user how much weight the pet gained
            Console.WriteLine($"{PetName} gained {GainedWeight}kgs");
            // Adding info to list
            FeedList.Add($"{PetName} ate {FoodAmount} treats and gained {GainedWeight}kgs ");
            // Display current weight message to user
            Console.WriteLine($"Current weight is now: {PetWeight}kgs");
            repeat = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{PetName} can only eat up to 5 treats at a time. Please enter a number that ranges from 0 - 5");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `float.TryParse`, if it returns false then it is not a valid floating point value.

Comment: Your question as it is worded doesn't make sense. The user input is **always** a string. Console.Readline returns string. Your question should be "How do I check if the input from the user can't be parsed to a float". To which the answer is to use `float.TryParse` as @hijinxbassist commented.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-determine-whether-a-string-represents-a-numeric-value